# Synchronize branches in mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial

I've got two branches, *A* and *B*. How do I merge *A* -> *B* so that both branches are exactly equal, meaning that

- if there's a file in *A*, it is in *B* with the exact same contents
- if a file is missing in *A*, it will not be found in *B*

A simple merge tool "to take *A* in a case of merge conflict" would take care of the extra files. Is it safe to remove all files in *B* and then do a merge from *A*?

Comment: What if you've added a file in B that you have not added in A?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: then it shouldn't be in *B* after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want to merge *A -> B*, such that the resulting merge *M* is equal to *A*?

For that, you can use `hg revert --all -r X` to set the entire working directory equal to what it was in revision *X*.

```
hg up B
hg merge A

# This will also delete or add files as needed
hg revert --all -r A

# Whatever merge conflicts we got, we resolved them by
# using A's version, so let's mark all as resolved
hg resolve --mark --all

# Commit and compare the current commit to A
hg commit
hg diff -r . -r A  # identical
```